# JSX - How put icons inside svg circle, react native

Tags: svg, react-native, jsx

I've been trying to put icons (http://fontawesome.io/icons/) inside a svg circle, in react native, but it doesn´t work. I´m working in JSX. Also, I need to put the icons next to the border of the circle, is that possible?

```
        <Svg style={{flex:1}}>
            <g>
                <Circle
                    cx={window.width/2}
                    cy={window.height/2.5}
                    r={window.width/2.1}
                    fill="grey"
                    fillOpacity= {0.3}
                    stroke="black"
                    strokeWidth="2.5"
                >
                <Icon name="minus-circle" style={{fontSize: 20}}/>
                </Circle>
            </g>
        </Svg>
```

Comment: trying how? You've not shown us what you are doing so how can we tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I´m sorry, just edited the post, thank you for your time

Comment: Doesn't react want the tag to be <G> and not <g>? Also putting your Icon inside the circle is never going to work. It needs to be a sibling of the <Circle>

Comment: I just tried that, it did compiled, but it doesn´t show the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for anyone else with same problem.

It is worth noting that react-native-svg comes automatically installed in the create-react-native-app project.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import Svg, { Circle } from 'react-native-svg';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

export default class IconButton extends Component {
  _onPress () {
    console.log("pressed")
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
          <Svg height="100"
               width="100"
               style={{alignItems: "center", justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Icon name="upload" size={45}/>
            <Circle
              cx="50"
              cy="50"
              r="45"
              fill="gray"/>
          </Svg>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```